# Azure Data Factory Pipeline Consumption Details

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-monitoring, azure-billing

I got a Azure Data Factory provisioned and is being shared by different department for their piece of work.

Orchestration Framework is common. But individual pipelines are specific to the departments needs.

Now it's getting hard to split the bill between agencies.
How can I get the Consumption (DIU's) details from ADF by pipeline  to split the bill.

[image]

Or is there better way to do this?

Comment: It's very hard to split the bill. Pipeline run consumption doesn't show the actual price charged. We need calculate the price manually. The Azure bills only show the total cost. I think Data Factory produce team should improve this. You could add a new feedback and we can vote it.

Comment: Hi @Sreedhar, If my answer is helpful for you,  hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said, It's very hard to split the bill. Just for now, there isn't a better way to do this. The [pipeline run consumption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/plan-manage-costs#monitor-consumption-at-pipeline-run-level) view shows you the amount consumed for each ADF meter for the specific pipeline run, **but it does not show the actual price charged**, because the amount billed to you is dependent on the type of Azure account you have and the type of currency used.

We only can manually calculate the cost by the [Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=data-factory%2F)

The Azure bills only show the total cost, for example:
[image]

I think Data Factory produce team should improve this. Since we can see the pipeline run consumption, and login with the Azure account, it should know our Azure account type and the type of currency used. Default is USD.

I would suggest you add a new [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) and we can help you vote it.

HTH.