# Get the cost of an individual pipline execution in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm looking into using Azure Data Factory V2 for integration imports and want to know if there's a way to track the cost of individual pipelines being run?

For example if I had 3 pipelines which represented 3 different integrations would there be a way to see the cost incurred from each?

Is there also a way to do this in near real time, so that during a month I could somehow put a budget on each integration/pipeline?

Comment: No, we can't get the each pipeline cost in Data Factory, we must manually calculate the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Data Factory bills only show the total cost. We can't get the each pipeline cost in Data Factory, we must manually calculate the price.

We can see the pipeline level consumption: **Monitor-->Pipeline run-->Consumption:**
[image]

Azure [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/plan-manage-costs#monitor-consumption-at-pipeline-run-level) says that "**The pipeline run consumption view shows you the amount consumed for each ADF meter for the specific pipeline run, but it does not show the actual price charged**". We need manually calculate the cost by [Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=data-factory%2F).

For your questions, is there a way to see the cost incurred from each?

No, there isn't. Must manually calculate the cost.

Is there also a way to do this in near real time, so that during a month I could somehow put a budget on each integration/pipeline?

I'm afraid no.

Others have post almost same question, please ref here: [Azure Data Factory Pipeline Consumption Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65190593/azure-data-factory-pipeline-consumption-details/65196421#65196421)